# Works in Console but not in Script Editor

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

On QGIS, I am using a simple script to zoom the selected features. I write them in the Text Editor, but it didn't work until I used the console... and it does work. What kind of problem is this? Is there a token or anything I should introduce in the text editor?

```
municipios = QgsVectorLayer("\\","name","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(municipios)
l = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
expr = QgsExpression( "" )
it = l.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ))
itera = [i.id() for i in it]
l.setSelectedFeatures( itera )
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

This is the error message (but not having it in my console, only with Text Editor of QGIS)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "c:/users/miguel~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpmlvs3w.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       it = l.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr )) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Comment: Hi, please paste a minimal code example that works in the console but not in the text editor.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right

Comment: Can you paste it as text? It will make it much easier for people to help you ;)

Comment: Just so I understand. You run this code in an external text editor, separate from QGIS?

Comment: Well, I thinks this is right, I managed to write the code correctly

Comment: I run it in the TEXT EDITOR of QGIS (I can't use an IDE for other reasons)

Comment: Is this the script editor from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Comment: It is from the Python Console Plugin, selecting it from the toolbar

Comment: Try adding `import qgis` and `from qgis.utils import iface` at the start of your script.

Comment: File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/miguel~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpeixj_n.py", line 8, in <module>
    it = l.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

EVEN ADDING (sorry I forgot it) "from qgis.core import* " and "from qgis.utils import *"

Comment: @user64823 - Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/185006/edit) your post to include the error messages? This would again make it easier for others to read without having to go through the comments :)

Comment: @Joseph it is done. I don't know why it doesn't work in Text Editor but does in the Console..

Comment: @user64823 - Thanks for the edit. I've posted an answer which worked for me using the Text Editor. I think this line `l = iface.mapCanvas().layers()` was tripping up the script.

Comment: Sorry, I have already seen you comment to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following code in the **Python Console Editor** which I took from you, modified it a little and tested it on an example layer using the expression `"Year" = 2005`:

```
municipios = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/shapefile","name","ogr")
l = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(municipios)
expr = QgsExpression( """ "Year" = 2005 """ )
itera = [i.id() for i in l.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))]
l.setSelectedFeatures( itera )
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

---

The following image shows the extent of the selected features (marked as yellow):

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, it works but does nothing in my layer... It is a polygon layer, and I select a field, called MUNICIPIOS. 

Then, the expression is: " ' MUNICIPIOS ' = 'Alcobendas' "

Comment: @user64823 - You have to be careful here with expressions as sometimes it needs to know when to escape the number of quotation marks. I began using triple double quotes on either end of an expression so in your case: `""" "MUNICIPIOS" = 'Alcobendas' """`. Or did you already use the triple quotes?

Comment: well, I am using triple double quotes: """ "MUNICIPIOS" = 'Alcobendas' """ as you posted... It still doesn't work, I am reviewing all the code, it is like yours, and I watched some others, but they give me problems about the class properties. Then, I think the expression syntax is wrong. I have a field called MUNICIPIOS and a attribute called Alcobendas

Comment: @user64823 - Interesting, which QGIS version are you using? Could you upload your shapefile to a public server so that it could be tested?

Comment: It is QGIS Essen (latest),standalone version. Anyway, I was going to write you. 

I have chosen another field, and it works. Now, I am confused why the other field didn't... both are String type (one is 254 characters long but it is just a 5 letters word (I didn't modify this field) and the other one, which doesn't work, is 50 characters long (I modified it, but it hasn't got any domains or subtypes..))

Comment: @user64823 - Glad you found out that the problem is quite likely the field. I would suggest creating a new string field using the **Field Calculator** and copying over the features using the expression `"MUNICIPIOS"`. Then deleting the original field.

Comment: I did so, (ArcGIS...I am getting used to QGIS) then, exported to Shapefile.  Probably, this changed something in the field. I have already added a new field and deleted the previous one, "MUNICIPIOS". It works.
(I was thinking about the other fields which have accents, for example, there is one field called "Álamo, El" but it is not a problem

By the way, which public server is most recommended to upload data? This is for the next time..

Thank you very much, I hope this could have helped all of us for studies and for professional works.

Comment: @user64823 - You got it working so well done! I would avoid using accents for fields (and generally everything) to avoid non-ASCII related errors. Not sure which is the most popular file sharing server but I have seen quite a few people using Dropbox. And thank you, it certainly helped me learn more =)